# Unexpected token '{' at line 1

Tags: javascript, unexpected-token

Trying to run an *internal* Javascript code but it's giving me an unexpected token. I'm new at JS so I don't know what that means

Here is the code:

```
changeColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = blue;
};

document.button.onclick = changeColor();
```

Comment: don't you mean?  function changeColor() {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = blue;
        };   ???

Answer (score 1):

You should add `function` to declare it and add quotes to blue if it's a string and affect function ref to `onclick` not its result.

```js
function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

document.button.onclick = changeColor;
```

or

```js
const changeColor = ()=> {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}

document.button.onclick = changeColor;
```

Comment: You are invoking `changeColor()` not passing it as named function reference

Comment: Suggest you explain that change for OP to understand also since *"I'm new at JS"*

Answer (score 0):

add the word "function" in front of changeColor()

```
function changeColor() { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

To declare a function in JavaScript you need to use a `function` keyword.

```
function changeColor() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
};
```

[More about functions in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";` - Blue must be a string (you must wrap it in quotes) otherwise JavaScript will treat it as a variable and since you didn't declare variable called blue you will get a  Reference Error: `ReferenceError: blue is not defined`

`document.button.onclick = changeColor;`
You cannot invoke a function here. You just need to pass a function reference.

[About onclick event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

This piece of code will probably also throw you an error `TypeError: document.button is undefined`. To use onclick event handler you need to grab this button element first. Since I don't see your whole code lets assume you have something like this in your code: `<button id="btn">Click Me</button>`. You can use [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab this button element by its ID

```
const button = document.querySelector('btn');
button.onclick = changeColor;
```

Comment: Same comment as answer above.... you don't want to invoke the function at run time

Comment: You're absolutely right. I didn't notice that. I saw function without a "function" keyword and immediately wrote and answer. My bad :D

Comment: There's even a further bug of undefined variable. Best practice is to test your own answers and also explain all changes made

Comment: *To declare a function in JavaScript you need to use a function keyword.* ~ `const holdMyBeer = () => {}`